# React app - compile error - jest-diff/build/diffLines.d.ts(8,13): '=' expected

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, compilation

I hava a problem to compile react app. If I run npm run start I am getting an error:

```
Failed to compile
c:/wamp64-3-2-0/www/eliadmin-frontend/node_modules/jest-diff/build/diffLines.d.ts
TypeScript error in c:/wamp64-3-2-0/www/eliadmin-frontend/node_modules/jest-diff/build/diffLines.d.ts(8,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005

     6 |  */
     7 | import { Diff } from './cleanupSemantic';
  >  8 | import type { DiffOptions } from './types';
   |             ^
     9 | export declare const diffLinesUnified: (aLines: Array<string>, bLines: Array<string>, options?: DiffOptions | undefined) => string;
    10 | export declare const diffLinesUnified2: (aLinesDisplay: Array<string>, bLinesDisplay: Array<string>, aLinesCompare: Array<string>, bLinesCompare: Array<string>, options?: DiffOptions | undefined) => string;
    11 | export declare const diffLinesRaw: (aLines: Array<string>, bLines: Array<string>) => Array<Diff>;
```

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

What it means? lease help. Thanks.